# UDP socket not work with 3G network in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, udp, cfnetwork, cocoaasyncsocket

I was using [GCDAsyncUdpSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) , it was working fine with wifi network

but when I testing in 3g network, it seems not work.

is possible using GCDAsyncUdpSocket with 3G network ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, but it depends on your network provider. Most providers will not allow multicast, some don't allow UDP. In your case, this seems like the latter.